# Explanation behind equality

Tags: inequality

I've been reading a certain topic and I saw multiple papers make the argument that $(1 - 2\theta)a^{2} \ge \frac{b^{4}}{2} \Rightarrow a^{2} \ge \frac{b^{4}}{2(2\theta - 1)}$. However, shouldn't it be $a^2 \ge \frac{b^{4}}{2(1 - 2\theta)}$? I don't understand how they were able to switch the the brackets around. This is under the condition that $\theta > \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: You're missing $a^2$ in your inequalities right?

Comment: Did you forget a square root somewhere. Because i don't understand either implication.

Comment: Is there any condition given on $\theta$? E.g. $ \theta > \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes I was missing $a^{2}$ and also updated the condition

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $ \theta >  \frac{1}{2}$ then $ 1 - 2 \theta < 0 $.

What happens when you divide an inequality by a negative value?

Comment: Well, if $1-2\theta < 0$, we have an impossible condition to start with unless $a=b=0$, so anything can follow...

Comment: Why do you say it is an "impossible condition"?  You were **given** that $\theta> \frac{1}{2}$ so $2\theta> 1$, $0> 1- 2\theta$.  Your "impossible condition" **is** the given condition for the problem!

Comment: @Macavity I was wondering that too. Maybe that is the point of this part of the proof?